# Lightning Locker proxying simple strings too?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service, aura-if, lightning-base-component

I'm getting some strange results trying to do a simple demo of `lightning:radioGroup` using `aura:if` to conditionally render components. I've added a controller method to show the weirdness.

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:attribute name="opts" type="Map[]"
                    default="[
                             {'label': 'apples', 'value': 'a'},
                             {'label': 'oranges', 'value': 'o'}
                             ]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="value" type="String" default="o"/>
    <lightning:radioGroup type="button"
        aura:id="mygroup" onchange="{!c.myAction}"
        name="radioButtonGroup"
        label="Radio Button Group"
        options="{!v.opts}"
        value="{!v.value}"
        required="true" />
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.value=='a'}">
        <p>Option 1 is selected (simple).</p>
    </aura:if>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.value=='o'}">
        <p>Option 2 is selected (simple).</p>
    </aura:if>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!(''+v.value)=='a'}">
        <p>Option 1 is selected (coerced).</p>
    </aura:if>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!(''+v.value)=='o'}">
        <p>Option 2 is selected (coerced).</p>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    myAction : function(c, event, helper) {
        var value = c.get('v.value');
        console.log(value);
        console.log(value+'');
        console.log(value == 'a');
    }
})
```

So basically, on initial load with a default value of "o", it starts on oranges (option 2) and I get both Option 2 paragraphs rendering. Once I flip the button, I only get the "coerced" Option 2 paragraphs.

When I monitor in the browser's Developer Console, I see:

```
Proxy { <target>: Array[1], <handler>: Object }
WARNING: Unsupported a method: Symbol(Symbol.toPrimitive). Returning undefined
a
WARNING: Unsupported a method: Symbol(Symbol.toPrimitive). Returning undefined
true
```

So even though the selected radio option maps to the simple string "a", the result retrieved from it is still a proxied object.

**In the markup** this has the totally unintuitive effect of failing to meet an equality test with the string "a" in an `aura:if` statement. However, if I coerce the value to a string in the expression syntax by adding it to an empty string, the equality test now works.

**In the controller** this seems to still produce normally expected results (the proxy object passes an equality test with "a") aside from the `console.log` result. However, it does throw that strange error message.

FWIW: I already tried initializing `opts` in the controller instead of the view and I get the same result.

Is this a new and odd behaviour? Bug-report-worthy?

Answer (score 6):

The attribute `value` on the `lightning:radioGroup` is defined as an object.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_radioGroup.htm

But that's because it's defined on the generic `lightning:inputable` interface. The `lightning:radioGroup` component writes it as an array, and it gets lockerized.

Thanks to your detailed repro steps (really appreciated), I was able to validate the issue, and I have contacted the relevant team for clarification.

UPDATE: there is a known issue with the `lightning:radioGroup` value `onChange` handler: the value data type changes from String to Array.

Comment: Thanks JF. Let me know how this proceeds. It seems to me that the desired outcome should be for binding expressions to have intuitive results regardless of the involvement of Locker Service.

Comment: Is there a Link which we can follow on the Known Issues site?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is right behavior from javascript point of view. When component fire onchange it returned value in proxied object and that is why your UI fails because it can't compare array with String but when you do "" + you are interally calling [javascript datatype casting](http://2ality.com/2012/03/converting-to-string.html), to elaborate this more there are three approaches for converting to string in case if you don't know

- value.toString()
- "" + value (This is what you are following): The plus operator is fine for converting a value when it is surrounded by non-empty strings.
- String(value): This approach is nicely explicit: Apply the function String() to value.

so to get result without "" in your UI, add following code in your controller

```
({
   myAction : function(c, event, helper) {
    var value = c.get('v.value');
    console.log(value);
    console.log(value+'');
    console.log(value == 'a');
    var changeValue = event.getParam("value"); //get updated value
    c.set('v.value',String(changeValue));  //assign back to value attribute as string
instead of object
  }
})
```

Comment: I can see why JavaScript causes this to happen, however, from the point of view of data binding it should not be necessary to implement a controller method to do type casting just so that the `aura:if`can evaluate intuitively.

Comment: @CharlesT yes I agree with you and as JF acknowledged this defect we should hear from him very soon :)

Comment: the `String(value)` saved my day

Answer (score 0):

Looks like **Spring'18** has fixed the bug the value is a String not an Array anymore. 
Which means the workaround is now a bug. Happy fixing everyone

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I would think that, coercing it to a String for comparison should not cause anything to break once it returns an actual String.